# file_downloads..want to download an uploaded file

Tags: python, django, file-upload

hi to all
My project is to upload an excel file and display its content in a template.
i have uploaded to an excel file in django successfully by using models.FileField .now what i want is to download that particular file at my defined location(project).I am trying to click on that uploaded file but it is giving me error

Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8001/admin/ikapp1/fileupload/2/file/Erode/Erode_3.xls/

file upload object with primary key u'2/file/Erode/Erode_3.xls' does not exist.

Comment: You'll have to provide a lot more code than this.  We can't guess what your URL pattern looks like.  We can't guess what the relevant view function looks like, either.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but omit the last slash in the url? Usually that indicates that you want a directory.